# Removing a Maquette Projector

Tags: maquette

I noticed in the API that you can `stop` a Projector, but if it has already rendered some DOM, is there a way to remove it.  It appears calling `projector.stop()` only causes the projector to stop responding.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on the use case? Why would you want to stop the projector?

Comment: Sure.  Consider a single page application.  Where I would want to manage a "page" of my application by a projector, and add and remove that from my page.  I also might have regions of a page where I have a project managing several components, which I would want to dynamically add and remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 2.3, the maquette Projector has a [detach](http://maquettejs.org/docs/typedoc/interfaces/_maquette_.projector.html#detach) function, which can be used to stop a `renderMaquetteFunction`. The return value contains the DOM Node that can be removed. This seems to be what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes.  That is what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to instruct the projector to remove what has been rendered. You will have to keep track of which nodes you have appended/merged/etc and remove them yourself.

Comment: Johan, thanks for the information.  I noticed that VDom's get decorated with DOM node they are related to.  I assume I could "clean up" by interrogating those properties on the VDom nodes?

Comment: Yes you can. I recommend stopping the projector when you do this. 
It looks like you want to unregister a 'projection'. This might also be useful for other users.